# Which type is the X and Y position of a UIButton in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I am trying to read the current valkue of X and Y position of a UIButton using something like:

```
button01.frame.origin.x
```

if I want to put it in a variable, which data type is it? I have tried NSInteger and NSDecimal but they gave me errors...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it's a `float` or a `double`.

A view's `frame` is of type `CGRect`.

```
struct CGRect {
   CGPoint origin;
   CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

The `origin` value is a `CGPoint`, which contains two `CGFloat` values.

```
struct CGPoint {
   CGFloat x;
   CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;
```

And, finally, each component of a `CGPoint` is a `CGFloat`, which is a `float` or a `double` depending on whether your app is 32-bit or 64-bit.

```
typedef float CGFloat;    // 32-bit
typedef double CGFloat;   // 64-bit
```

If you need to store the origin or entire frame in an object you can use `NSValue`.

```
NSValue *originValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:button01.frame.origin];
NSValue *frameValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:button01.frame];
```

Or, to store a single `CGFloat` component, you can use `NSNumber`.

```
NSNumber *xValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:button01.frame.origin.x];
```